# Can't access a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

[image]

I have this data here in my ProductsShow.vue component and when I try to display the product's images through the `path` property I get this error

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"
```

ProductsShow.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="container mx-auto mt-10">
        <div class="flex">
            <!--            product-->
            <div class="w-2/3">
                <div class="flex">
                    <!--                    product image-->
                    <div class="w-1/2">
                        <vue-glide :per-view="1">
                            <vue-glide-slide v-for="image in product.images">
                                <div class="h-100 bg-red-500">
                                    <img :src="/images/ + image.path" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </vue-glide-slide>
                        </vue-glide>
                    </div>
                    <!--                    product details-->
                    <div class="w-1/2 bg-white px-4">
                        <p class="mt-4 text-xl font-bold text-gray-700">{{ product.name }}</p>
                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-red-500 fa-sm"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-red-500 fa-sm"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-red-500 fa-sm"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-red-500 fa-sm"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star text-red-500 fa-sm"></i>
                            <span class="text-sm text-gray-700">34 Reviews</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="mt-4 text-xl text-gray-900 font-bold">150 Dhs</p>
                        <div class="text-lg text-justify mt-4 leading-normal text-gray-700">
                            Open-source electronic prototyping platform enabling users to create interactive electronic objects.
                        </div>

                        <!--                        quantity-->
                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <button @click="stepDown" class="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 w-6 h-6 rounded-full focus:outline-none">
                                <span>&#65293;</span>
                            </button>
                            <input type="number" v-model="quantity" class="text-center w-8 outline-none" min="1">
                            <button @click="stepUp" class="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 w-6 h-6 rounded-full focus:outline-none">
                                <span>&#65291;</span>
                            </button>
                            <span class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-500">137 pieces available</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="my-4">
                            <button class="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-sm focus:outline-none">
                                Buy now
                            </button>
                            <button @click="addToCart" class="ml-2 bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-sm focus:outline-none">
                                Add to cart
                            </button>
                            <button class="ml-2 bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-sm focus:outline-none">
                                <i class="far fa-heart text-red-500"></i> 24
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-1/3">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="w-1/2 bg-gray-500 h-40"></div>
                    <div class="w-1/2 bg-gray-400 h-40"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { Glide, GlideSlide } from 'vue-glide-js';
    import 'vue-glide-js/dist/vue-glide.css';
    export default {
        name: "ProductsShow",

        components: {
            [Glide.name]: Glide,
            [GlideSlide.name]: GlideSlide
        },

        mounted() {

            axios.get('/api/products/' + this.$route.params.id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.product = response.data.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert('Unable to fetch product.')
                });

        },

        data: function() {
            return {
                product: null,
                quantity: 1
            }
        },

        methods: {

            addToCart: function() {
                this.product.quantity = this.quantity;
                axios.post('/api/cart', this.product)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {

                    });
            },

            stepDown: function () {
                if (this.quantity > 1) {
                    this.quantity--;
                }
            },

            stepUp: function () {
                this.quantity++;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    input[type="number"] {
        -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        appearance: textfield;
    }
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should never trust the data from another place like a remote server

The code is pretty easy to be broken by invalid data, such as null product, null images, image without the path. So in the actual practice of play with the data, it very much recommended to add the type and value check to ensure the accessing is always safe.

As in Vuejs, it's pretty easy to achieve that by using v-if, only render the piece of template when the preserved data(product,images,image) is provided as expected. This is called as 'Defensive Programming'.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have already used v-if="product.images" but got this

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of null"

Comment: The problem is this is an array of objects. I have no idea how to initialize an empty value to that

Comment: Try v-if="product & product.image" instead since product probably be null as well. And what is 'an array of objects'? The images?

Comment: Yeah look up the data in the image above and this v-if thing brings this error [Cannot read property 'images' of null] since the images are not initialized by default

Comment: @OthmaneBoumediane v-if="product & product.image" skips the render until the property images is updated to not null.  Isn't it solve the problem?

Comment: It did not! I still get the same error I think I should initialize the array of images but this images:[] not working

Comment: My bad, it shoud be v-if="product && product.images"

Comment: Yeah I know that's what I did but still sad face :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205902/discussion-between-pengson-and-othmane-boumediane).

Comment: I just initialized the product like this product: {} and then used v-if="product.images" and it worked IDK why but I don't really care

Answer (score 0):

try if this works

```js
    data: function () {
      return {
        product: {
          name:'',
          images:[]
        },
        quantity: 1
      }
    },
```

Comment: I kinda fixed the problem by assigning null to product property and I can get the images path but still got this warning

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of null"

Comment: if you are sure about how many props in this.product,try to initialize them with empty value,like 
product : { images : [ ]  }

Comment: It is good that you're trying to help @waiaan. 

It would be better if you can spend a moment to refer below guidelines from Stackoverflow about how to write a good answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

You should only post an answer if it gives the solution and if you are looking for more information then you can use comments for it.

Comment: The images property is an array of objects how do I initialize that with empty values?

Comment: I have and I got this

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a new property `images: []` and use that for the loop instead of `image in product.images`.
For example, change in your code like:

```
<vue-glide :per-view="1">
  <vue-glide-slide v-for="image in images">
    <div class="h-100 bg-red-500">
      <img :src="/images/ + image.path" alt="">
    </div>
  </vue-glide-slide>
</vue-glide>
```

```
data () {
  return {
    product: null,
    images: [],
    quantity: 1
  }
},
mounted() {
  axios.get('/api/products/' + this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.product = response.data.data;
      if (response.data.data.images) {
        // Check if images exist in response.data.data
        this.images = response.data.data.images
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert('Unable to fetch product.')
    });
}
```